# Prevent binary data in text area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

in admin panel user post new news and in content of news user can copy image from word and this image will be store directly into database as binary data. so database size will increase too much.

I wanna prevent user from input binary data , I mean I wanna let users just input string and nothing more.

how to implement that ?

*( I use ASP.NET MVC 2 and used [AllowHtml] attribute for content property of news entity)*

TNX in forward :)